# Work Permit for Summer Work In UK

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I am originally from Pakistan, and am now studying in Germany. If I wanted to do a summer internship in UK (full time) what type of Visa would I need? Is this possible at all?

I see that Tier 2 (General would be best), but on some pages, minimum wage of 20,500 pound was mentioned (which is impossible for any Summer Internship).

Answer (score 4):

To do a full-time internship in the UK you would need a Tier 5 visa, not a Tier 2. And specifically, you would apply for a [Tier 5 (Temporary Worker - Government Authorised Exchange) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-government-authorised-exchange/overview).

The sponsor offering you the internship must be listed on the [Tier 5 sponsor register](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers) and you would need to meet the qualification requirements. As your question was posted over 2 1/2 years ago, I assume you would have learned this already, but should check the links anyway because there have been significant rule changes in the meantime.